# Automate sequence of key strokes in Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, automation, automator

I want to automate a long sequence of keystrokes that I have to type every time I use a specific web site. How can I do it in Mac OS X. I've tried the Automator. I record the sequence, but when I run it I got this error:

> The action “Watch Me Do” encountered an error.
>
> Check the actionʼs properties and try running the workflow again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To do this, I created a automator workflow with a Run AppleScript object with this content:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "A"
    keystroke "B"
    keystroke "C"
end tell

return input
 end run
```

This worked fine for me

Comment: On OS X El Capitan I got an error when including the first and last two lines. Removing them made the script work fine.

Comment: This was clutch because none of the other answers worked for me (I wanted to send only arrow keys and most of the gui apps I tried didn't even have the option). Using the Script Editor utility this did the trick, although originally got an Apple events error (error number -1721: [wrong number of arguments](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html)) I had to remove the `{input, parameters}` arguments from `on run` and the line `return input`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to writing your own script, [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) can be used to compose key sequences like this.

Comment: I've used Keyboard Maestro -- excellent product and great support!

Answer (score 3):

You could create a macro with an application like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/), [iKey](http://plumamazing.com/mac/ikey) or [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/). Many of them also support something like the quick macros in Keyboard Maestro. You can press ⌃F1 to start or stop recording a macro, and then play it back with ⌥F1.

You can also emulate keypresses with AppleScript. The delay at the start is not needed if the script is run with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

```
delay 0.5 -- if the script is run with a shortcut that has modifier keys
activate application "TextEdit"
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "aa"
    key code 123 using {shift down, command down}
end tell
```

The `keystroke` command can only be used to insert characters that are included in the current keyboard layout. If the text is long enough, there's also a visible delay when it's inserted.

Another way to insert text is to use the clipboard:

```
set the clipboard to "aa"
delay 0.05
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

Answer (score 3):

I've authored a tool called [`sendkeys`](https://github.com/socsieng/sendkeys) which can be used to send keystrokes and mouse events to an application.

Example, the following script will activate Google Chrome, open a new tab and navigate to Google:

```
sendkeys -a 'Google Chrome' -c '<c:t:command>www.google.com<c:enter>'
```

It can be installed with `brew`:

```
brew install socsieng/tap/sendkeys
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [iKey](http://www.plumamazing.com/mac/ikey) and [QuicKeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/).  I don't think either one will do more than Automator/AppleScript will in this case, but they might be handy otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot add a mouseclick function in any of these or workflow. Even applescript has a difficult time implementing a mouse click in an app.